# No installation candidate for "libicu52" on 15.10

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation

When I try to install `sudo apt-get install libicu52`, I get the following error.
I'm using Ubuntu 15.10, 64 bit.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package libicu52 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libicu52' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: what is the current version for this?  is there a meta package?

Answer (score 5):

Install `libicu55` instead:

```
sudo apt-get install -y libicu55
```

You can also search for this package:

```
sudo apt-get update
apt-cache search libicu
```

If the latter command gives you some results (eg. `libicu` with version number other than `52`) you can check if installing it suits your needs.

Comment: "Try" is an indicator that this post should rather be a comment than an answer. Especially as it's not really a final solution but just a hint.

Comment: But [searching for package names containing `libicu` for 15.10](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libicu&searchon=names&suite=wily&section=all) returns that there exists a package **`libicu55`** which is probably what the OP wants. If you [edit] your answer to add that, it will become a good one and receive an upvote :)

Comment: after i text     "sudo apt-get update
apt-cache search libicu55" , i got this message "libicu55 - International Components for Unicode
libicu55-dbg - International Components for Unicode
"

Comment: This is not a solution if you want to install `libicu52`. For example, if you want to install openttd.

Comment: Also required for [powershell_6.0.0-rc-1.ubuntu.16.04](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/docs/installation/linux.md#ubuntu-1604) which doesn't use libicu55.  The solution posted by Alejandro Pinzon above to manually download and install libicu52 worked.

Answer (score 5):

you can download deb package from

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/wily/+package/libicu52

works for me.

Comment: Include essential part of the solution

Comment: - I installed Gdebi package manager  - download the Binary package “libicu52” ( libicu52_52.1-8_<your architecture>.deb, download the package depending of your architecture ) 
- then you can install the package libicu52_52.1-8_<your architecture>.deb with gdeby  

- i used the this package on ubuntu 16.04LTS and works for me.

Comment: Good. But add your comment to your answer. This way, it will become useful for others. Thanks

Comment: No package is available on the mentioned link. The link gives a message - `No summary available for libicu52 in ubuntu wily.`

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/i/icu/libicu52_52.1-3ubuntu0.8_amd64.deb
dpkg -i libicu52*.deb
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/en/trusty/libicu52). So download the `.deb` package and install manually by:

```
sudo dpkg -i libicu52_52.1-3ubuntu0.8_amd64.deb
```

See: http://packages.ubuntu.com/en/trusty/libicu52`

Answer (score 1):

Just ran into this today. I fixed it by adding the microsoft packages to my `apt-get` sources like so:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/16.04/prod xenial main"
```

Then:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

And then `libicu52` installed.

Found [here](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3876).